# how to display the multi-level menu in CodeIgniter using twig

Tags: php, codeigniter, menu, twig, multi-level

sorry I am still a beginner in CodeIgniter I want to ask how to display the multi-level menu in CodeIgniter using twig
I want to like this
- Menu 1.1
- Menu 1.1.2
--- menu 1.1.2.3
-Menu 1.2
--menu1.2.1
I've made a multi-level menu script but does not function
source
menu_controller.php

```
 function __construct ()
 {

     $this->load->model("blog/menu_model");
     $menu = array();
     $menu = $this->menu_model->get_by(array(
         "hide" => 1,
         "parent" => 0,
     ));
     foreach($menus as $m => $submenu)
     {
         $submenu[$menu[$m]["id"]] = $ci->menu_model->get_by(array(
             "hide" => 1,
             "parent" => $menu[$m]["id"],
         ));
     }
     $ci->twig->set_variable("menu", $menu);
     $ci->twig->set_variable("submenu", $submenu);

 }
```

MY_Model.php

```
public function get_by($filter = array(), $limit = 0, $offset = 0, $sort = array(), $debug = 0) {
        $this->db->from("menu");

        if(!empty($filter)) {
            $this->db->where($filter);
        }

        if(!empty($sort)) {
            foreach($sort as $key => $value) {
                $this->db->order_by($key, $value);
            }
        } elseif(!is_array($sort)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("warning", "Pengurutan data pada database tidak valid !");
            log_message("error", "Mode pengurutan data pada database tidak valid !");

            return false;
        }

        if($limit > 0) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }

        if($debug) {
            var_dump($this->db->_compile_select());
        }

        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
```

menu_view.php

```
<ul class = "main-menu">
{% For menus in menu%}
{% If menus.position == "mainmenu"%}
<li style = "background: # 264c84; color: # 264c84;"> <a href="{{ menus.muri menus.name }}"> {{}} {% if submenu [menus.id] | length> 0%} <span> & nbsp; </ span> {% endif%} </a>
{% If submenu [menus.id] | length> 0%}
<ul class = "sub-menu">
{% For the sub in the submenu [menus.id]%}
<li> <a href="{{ sub.muri sub.name }}"> {{}} </a> </ li>
{% Endfor%}
</ ul>
{% Endif%}
</ li>
{% Endif%}
{% Endfor%}
</ ul>
```

[screen shot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1GFt.png)

[My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laa9L.png)

Menu multi level 3 can't display

Comment: What is error you have got? Fix those spaces. Remove those. Check here what is [CodeIgniter coding standard](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html).

Comment: menu level 3 can't display

Comment: Insufficient data. You have to fix syntax here. There is too many space errors. For example: `$ menu = array ();` won't work ever. Also if you need someone's help, you need to show model code and table structure maybe.

Comment: I attach the model code already let you see again

Answer (score 0):

PHP CODE

```
function __construct()
{

    $this->load->model("blog/menu_model ");
    $menu = array();
    $menu = $this->menu_model->get_by(array(
        "hide" => 1,
        "parent" => 0,
    ));
    foreach ($menus as $m => $submenu)
    {
        $submenu [$menu [$m] ["id"]] = $ci->menu_model->get_by (array (
        "hide" => 1,
        "parent" => $menu [$m] ["id"],
        ));
        $menu[$m]['submenu'] = $submenu;
    }
    $ci->twig->set_variable ("menu", $menu);

}
```

Twig Code

```
<ul class = "main-menu">
    {% For menus in menu%}
    {% If menus.position == "mainmenu"%}
    <li> 
        <a href="{{ menus.muri menus.name }}"> {{}} {% if menu['submenu'] | length> 0 %} <span> & nbsp; </ span> {% endif%} </a>
        {% If menu['submenu'] | length> 0%}
        <ul class = "sub-menu">
            {% For sub in  menu['submenu'] %}
            <li> <a href="{{ sub.muri sub.name }}"> {{sub.name}} </a> </li>
                {% Endfor %}
             </ul>
        {% Endif%}
    </li>
    {% Endif%}
    {% Endfor%}
</ul>
```

Comment: even all menus level can not be displayed